# Regex capture character set but not some specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Javascript regex

I want to capture all characters in this set

```
([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~._|\?]{2,})
```

but I dont want ending `~~` `||` `##` to be captured.

Eg:

```
It@was@022342@whate@~f56@|fdsdfw&~~
```

should result in caputre of

```
It@was@022342@whate@~f56@|fdsdfw&
```

Comment: Will `~~`, `||`, `##` always be at the end of the string?

Comment: It may or may not be there, at the end.

Comment: What do you mean by "but I dont want ending"? Is expected result `"@022342@", "@~", "56@|", "&`?

Comment: I mean captured characters should not contain `~~` `||` `##` if one or more of these character sets exist at the end of string

Comment: _"if one or more of these character sets exist at the end of string"_ Why do you list pairs of the characters if requirement is "one or more"?

Comment: I mean the string `whatis90||##` should result in capture of `whatis90`

Comment: Then no `~~`, `||`, or `##` characters should be captured?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: You could try -> `/([-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~._|\?]{2,}?)(?:[~|\||#\s]*)?$/i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

```
re = /([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~._|\?]{2,}?)(?:(~~|##|\|\|)+)/i
```

Working example:

```js
re = /([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~._|\?]{2,}?)(?:(~~|##|\|\|)+)/i
str = "It@was@022342@whate@~f56@|fdsdfw&~~"
console.log(str.match(re)[1])

str = "It@was@022342@whate@~f56@|fdsdfw&##"
console.log(str.match(re)[1])

str = "It@was@022342@whate@~f56@|fdsdfw&||"
console.log(str.match(re)[1])

str = "It@was@022342@whate@~f56@|fdsdfw&||##"
console.log(str.match(re)[1])

str = "It@was@022342@whate@~f56@|fdsdfw&##||"
console.log(str.match(re)[1])
```

Comment: `whatis90||##` doesn't come out as whatis90.

Comment: Hey Dekel, can you modify this to allow ending `||` `##` `~~` to be removed, even if one or two or all three sets occur simultaneously at the end

Comment: let me take a look

Comment: `/([-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~._|\?]{2,}?)(?:[~|\||#]{2})*$/i`

Comment: @Keith that one will also remove `~#~` from the end, and it is not what the OP wanted

Comment: Oh,..  yeah.. well, still learning regex.  still plenty to learn.. :)

Comment: The first re= line should have a + at the end, before last bracket

Comment: Correct. Updated the snippet and not the code. Now it's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a cleverer way to do this, but here's a pretty straightforward approach:

`([-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~._|\?]{2,}?)(?:~~|\|\||##)?$`

https://regex101.com/r/E9htiV/1

Comment: Almost exactly the same time I answered :) You got my vote here!

Answer (score 0):

As of the comments above, I think you want to remove `~~` `||` `##` from your string `str`, you can do it simply like this:

```
str.replace(/(~~|\|\||##)/g, "");
```

Or if you want to remove just from the end of your string

```
str.replace(/(~~|\|\||##)+$/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
str.replace(/[\|#~]*$/,'');
```

For example:

```
var str = "It@was@022342@whate@~f56@|fdsdfw&~~";
str.replace(/[\|#~]*$/,'');

"It@was@022342@whate@~f56@|fdsdfw&"
```

Also works if you have any combination of `~`, `#` and `|` at the end

```
var str = "It@was@022342@whate@~f56@|fdsdfw&~#|"
str.replace(/[\|#~]*$/,'');

"It@was@022342@whate@~f56@|fdsdfw&"
```